# JQuery read Text and safe to 2D Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a .txt file as input and would like to save it into a 2 Dimensional Array

Example Input:

> 21 16 91 //1st block of data
>
> 22 156 106 //2nd block of data
>
> 23 120 164 //3rd block of data
>
> 24 159 207 //etc
>
> 25 168 83
>
> 26  83 27
>
> 27 189 29

Code so far:

```
function leseConfig (input) {
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {

};
```

How can I achieve what I´m seeking for ?

Maybe someone can give me a short example on doing something like this ?

Comment: @downvoter what is wrong with my Question? From my point of view its well structured and ontopic?

Comment: How do you suppose to push this data for 3-dimensional array? For me, your data looks like 2-dimensional array (array of 3-element arrays)

Comment: @FelixLahmer You can't read files directly from the user's file system quite like you think you can.  There are very good reasons why one should never be allowed to do this in Javascript.

Comment: @kevin628 I did never plan to do this :D user uplaods a file^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually read `input` file after `reader` preparing you can use

```
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
```

To get text of read file inside `reader.onload` you can use

```
reader.result
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sum4x61/).

So having HTML:

```
<input id="file" type="file"/>
<input id="read" type="button" value="read"/>
```

You can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#read').click(function()
    {
        leseConfig($('#file')[0]);
    });
});

function leseConfig(input)
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0])
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function()
        {
            var arr = [];
            var rows = reader.result.split('\n');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
            {
                var elements = rows[i].split(/\s/);
                if (elements.length >= 3)
                {
                    arr.push([elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]]);
                }
            }
            handleArray(arr);
        }
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to convert your file into 2D Array:

```
var array;
function leseConfig (input) 
{
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
     {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
            array = e.target.result.split('\n');
            for(key in array)
                array[key] = array[key].split(' ');
        }
     }
}
```